# Changing app publisher in Apple App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is it possible to change the publisher of an app after it has been published in the app store? We are founding a company, and would like to publish the first version of the app soon under my developer license, and then transfer it under the name of our company, once it has been founded.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked in the App Store Helpdesk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to reports, it is not possible to transfer an app between 2 developer accounts.  In the case of 2 company accounts, if one corporation completely acquires another corporation, and can present legal proof of that merger to Apple, there have been reports that the apps can get merged into 1 account, essentially transferring apps to the acquiring corporation.

The other solution is for the original developer to remove the app from sale, and the acquiring developer to reintroduce the app as a new app under their name.  Earlier purchasers will be left without any support.

UPDATE: As of June 2013, Apple has added the ability to transfer apps between iOS developer accounts, subject to some restrictions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html